# jscrollpane: stop autoscrolling when mouse is over the scroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I use the following script to start autoscrolling when page load

```
$(function(){

var pane = $('.wrapperContent');

pane.jScrollPane({
    horizontalDragMaxWidth: 86,
    horizontalDragMinWidth: 86,
    animateScroll: true,
    animateDuration : 20000
});

var api = pane.data('jsp');

api.scrollToX(parseInt(900));
return false;
});
```

But I would stop autoscroll when mouse is over the content.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was, I created a timer variable and set the autoReinitialise settings to TRUE. Then, I set the timer to my function and cleared it on hover. take a look:

```
var timer;
function autoScrollFunction() {
//your function to auto scroll
}
timer = setInterval(changeImageFeature);


$("#super_feature").hover(function () {
   clearInterval(timer); // stop the timer
}
```